# belongsTo with nullable?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

While reading the grails official guide, I've got question about belongsTo with many-to-one relationship.

When I define two classes, Face and Nose as listed below:

```
class Face {

    String name
    Nose nose

    static constraints = {
    }
}


class Nose {

    String color

    static belongsTo = [face: Face]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

I think that we can make Face instance in two ways:

1. Making face with nose at the same time

   ```
   def rudolph = new Face(name: 'Rudolph', nose: new Nose('color': 'Red')).save(failOnError: true)
   ```
2. Making a nose, and face in sequence

   ```
   def nose = new Nose(color: 'Red').save(failOnError: true)
   def rudolph = new Face(name: 'Rudolph', nose: nose).save(failOnError: true)
   ```

However, both give me an error like:

```
Fatal error running tests: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
- Field error in object 'relationship.Nose' on field 'face': rejected value [null]; codes
```

Of course, if I put the constraints in Nose, it works:

```
class Nose {

    String color

    static belongsTo = [face: Face]

    static constraints = {
        face nullable: true
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if the back reference property must be always nullable or not.

Another question is the following static property works because it doesn't have "face" property:

```
    static belongsTo = Face
```

If it doesn't have back reference property name, why do we define belongsTo property?

Answer (score 0):

1. In the case you define one-to-one relationship and therefore you don't need to have "belongsTo". You can remove it from "Nose" class and it will be fine. More over you don't have to save "Nose" instance, just create it and add it to "Face" and save "Face" instance. Details: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasOne.html
2. "belongsTo" needs to be defined when you have one-to-many or many-to-many relationship. It has to do with saves and cascading deletes. Link for the question "why": http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html

Comment: belongsTo description from the manual describes many-to-one relationship. Can I ignore this relationship? I need to consider one-to-many only. Some manuals/tutorials on the internet makes me confused. Thank you.

Comment: In your question above, you don't need belongsTo. As for other cases you will have to show code